# I'm having issues using a Gem (AutoStripAttributes) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This is odd, I've used many gems before and am using various gems throughout my project.

I'm attempting to use a gem right now called AutoStripAttributes ( https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes )

I've included it in my gemfile (`gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 2.0"`), and ran a `bundle install`.

`Installing auto_strip_attributes 2.0.6`

It's all good.

However, when I go to use it...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :...
  has_many :...
  has_many :...
  has_many :...

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { maximum: 25 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 255 }

  has_secure_password validations: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true 

  auto_strip_attributes :name
```

I get the following output...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `auto_strip_attributes' for #<Class:0x007fe929502f7>):
  app/models/user.rb:21:in `<class:User>'
  app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Why isn't this working?

EDIT:

```
rails c
AutoStripAttributes

2.1.3 :079 > AutoStripAttributes
NameError: uninitialized constant AutoStripAttributes
from (irb):79
from /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/a/Developer/rails/fffapi/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/a/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/a/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

and...

```
a$ bundle show | grep auto_strip_attributes
  * auto_strip_attributes (2.0.6)
```

Comment: Does `ActiveRecord::Base.auto_strip_attributes` in your IRB console returns something other than "undefined method" ?

Comment: What's on line 21 of app/models/user.rb ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji it returns "NoMethodError: undefined method `auto_strip_attributes' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class"

Comment: @PrakashMurthy It's the `auto_strip_attributes :name` code line in the OP above.

Comment: Have you restarted your rails server after the gem installation..?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I just ran another bundle install and restarted the server. It's all good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed here to test and all worked fine.

In your Gemfile, are you forcing this gem to be loaded just on a specific group?

Ex.:

```
gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 2.0", group: :production
```

Or:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 2.0"
end
```

at console (`rails c`), what is returned when you call `AutoStripAttributes`? Its something like that?

```
$ rails c

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.2.0 :001 > AutoStripAttributes
 => AutoStripAttributes
```

or are you having a `NameError: uninitialized constant AutoStripAttributes` error?

Also, what is the result of `bundle show | grep auto_strip_attributes`?

Comment: It's not forced to any specific group, so I 'should' be getting it. When I try 'AutoStripAttributes' from console I get an error. I put the results in my original post above.

Comment: I ran another `bundle install` and now everything is fine